# multiple router-outlet in file don't work with lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

i have my app-component.html file like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="menu"></router-outlet>
```

my app-routing.ts like this:

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./features/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
{ path: '', outlet: 'menu', loadChildren: () => import('./features/catalog/catalog.module').then(m => m.CatalogModule)}
```

But when i launch my app i have this errors:

```
core.js:4352 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at getChildConfig (router.js:3046)
```

It seems that it's a known error and that it can't work, so i tried this:

```
  {
    path: '',
    outlet: 'menu',
    component: MenuProxyRouteComponent,
    children: [{
      path: 'test',
      loadChildren: () => import('./features/catalog/catalog.module').then(m => m.CatalogModule)
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'test', pathMatch: 'full' }
  ]
  },
```

With my MenuProxyRouteComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'menu-proxy-route',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class MenuProxyRouteComponent {
}
```

I don't have the previous error but now i have this:

```
    ERROR in src/renderer/app/features/menu/menu.proxy.component.ts:5:16 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
    1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    5     template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
```

I don't understand why i have this error because i have a  in the app.component.html file and it works fine.

Anyone know how to have multiple  in app.component.html working with lazy loading? Or why i have this second error?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it using an example. For this multiple `router-outlet`

```
<router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
```

Try change the `app-routing.module` or relevant routing file as follows

```
{
  path: 'list',
  component: LeftComponent,
  outlet: 'left'
},
{
  path: ':id',
  component: RightComponent,
  outlet: 'right'
}
```

Comment: It works well with components, but i want the same with lazy-loading and with the path '' bc i want the default page loaded without user action